# Apple iChat & MobileMe & GTalk

Tags: chat, google-talk, mobileme, ichat

I am signed into iChat with my Mobile Me account,
Is there a way to add google talk contacts to the account and chat through iChat?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to [configure iChat](http://www.google.com/support/chat/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=24076) to connect to Google Talk:

1. Open iChat.
2. From the iChat menu, select Preferences...
3. Click Accounts along the top of the dialogue box.
4. Click the + button along the bottom to add a new account.
5. Select Jabber Account from the Account Type drop-down menu.
6. Enter the following information in the appropriate fields:

   - Jabber ID:

     - If you're signing in with a Gmail or Google Mail username, enter your full email address.
     - If your Google Talk username isn't associated with any Google email product, add `@gmail.com` to the end of your username. For example, `iloveyoko` will become `iloveyoko@gmail.com`
     - If you're a Google Apps user, enter your full email address (`gordon@example.com`).
     - Password: `Your password`.
     - Server: `talk.google.com`
7. Click Add.
8. Highlight your new account in the Accounts section, and then click Server Settings.
9. Enter the following information in the appropriate fields:

   - Server: `talk.google.com`
   - Port: `5223`

     [image: Accnt. Prefs]
10. Check the boxes next to Connect using SSL and Allow self-signed certificates. You don't need to check the box next to Warn before password is sent insecurely -- your password is always secure with Google Talk.
11. Enter iChat in the Location field. If this field is left blank, you won't be able to sign in.